# Как на WP сайте в темном режиме отображать картинки неизменно?

Tags: css, wordpress, плагин

Использую на моем WP сайте https://transscreen.ru плагин "DarkLooks - Dark Mode Switcher For WordPress" https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/darklooks-dark-mode-switcher/ чтоб пользователи могли переключится в темный режим.

В настройках плагина выставил использование для темного режима метода инверсии цветов:
[image]

Вижу что в темном режиме картинке плагин задаёт этот CSS , где 1 - означает что плагин инвертирует картинку обратно ("реанимирует") из инвертированной картинки, но при этом очень сильно уменьшает яркость:
[image]

Фрагмент CSS:

```
html.darklooks-mode-changer-enabled img {
    filter: invert(1);
}
```

Если я вставлю в CSS такой фильтр `filter: brightness(100%);` то он запрещает фильтр инверсии который нужен для реанимации картинки из инвертированного режима:
[image]

Где находится "цифра" что отвечает за уменьшения яркости я не могу найти.

Вопрос: Как в темном режиме отображать картинки неизменно - без уменьшения яркости и без инверсии?
Или где хотяб найти цифру где он уменьшает яркость картинке?

Comment: Может проще спросить на форуме поддержке данного плагина, что именно вам необходимо. Всё что вам тут на подсказывают будут жосткими костылями.

Comment: на форуме поддержки молчат(

Когда включен темный режим то в заголовке страницы я вижу что стоить грейскейл .8 изменение этого параметра не помогает изменить только картинку. см скриншот: https://imgur.com/a/Nj7jitE

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте повысить специфичность `css` классов, что-то на подобии

```
html.darklooks-mode-changer-enabled body img {
    filter: initial;
}
```

но это всё костыли, лучше спросить у разработчиков, как не подключать какие-то хуки.